# How adjust my app in Android 11 in cell phone screen?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Before Android 11, I've adjusted my app to fullscreen easily

My old phone had the camera hole and base buttons outside the screen area, my new phone has a camera hole and the base buttons inside a screen.

With few settings, my app was fullscreen in the old phone.

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>   
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>    
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
   ...       
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</application>
```

In my new phone with  *Android 11*, I've searched many `Stackoverflow` question. I've tried many different solutions.  In the end, I put in my app the following code in that start of `OnCreate()`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
  window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
 else {
      @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
      window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
      )
    }
```

I wanted a narrow margin near the base buttons and the camera hole, like Chrome.

But all can I get is a wide margin between the app and button (downward) and between the app and the camera hole (upward):

[image: App 1]

But I would want a narrow  margin:

[image: Ideal]

similar to Chrome browser for Android:

[image: My wish]

How can I do this programatically?

I haven't been able to find a single clue to my problem in Internet (and StackOverflow)

I also haven't been able to figure out how to identify if a given cell phone has the camera hole on the screen or if it has the base buttons on the screen. It looks like it's based on [`DisplayCutout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/DisplayCutout), `WindowInsets` and `boundingRectTop` and `boundingRectBottom`, but there is no real and clear usage example in Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer will surprise many, as it surprised myself. It was months and months of attempts and errors, frustrated help requests, until I reached the solution myself.

It is of a disconcerting simplicity, but at the same time, It was the most complicated thing in the galaxy, including the boldness of trying it

The magic and secret line is:

```
      <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.4"/>
```

2.4 is maximum `screen height / screen width` allowed for the app area in the screen.

If you omit this statement, the system still [assumes](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) that the maximum aspect ratio is 1.86.

I don't know why the system assumes a default so low, if many devices today has a ratio  `screen height /screen width` greater than 1.86.

From what I've written inside the question, one really needs to change one of the standard styles of Android

So in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme"> parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>   
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` includes

```
  <application
    ... 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.4"/>
    ...  
   <\application>
```

It's all...

The only remote reference I found on this subject was on the official blog of developers on a 2017 page in [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html) post.