# How to put an application on a full screen in the newer versions of Android?

Tags: android

I have a old problem to put my app in (almost) full screen mode (short edges) in my Android 11 (and now 12) Samsung cell phone as I've explained  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948103/how-adjust-my-app-in-android-11-in-cell-phone-screen).

My app has this look

[image: My app]

And I would like this look

[image: My wish]

Today I've discovered that my app, can be configurated in
`Settings`, `Display`, `Full Screen Apps`.

[image: Full screen apps]

My app is between the listed apps that allows to select between full screen mode and app default. Many apps don't appear on this list. I don't know what criterion Android uses to select the apps where it's posible to change the screen.

So I managed to change the app screen the way I wanted.

The only question is that the system displayed a white background navigation bar, so I had to add to the style setting in `Styles.xml` the following line:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

However, I would love to do it programmatically. But I don't get it, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948103/how-adjust-my-app-in-android-11-in-cell-phone-screen). I did a lot of research, a lot of Stackoverflow research, but nothing.

Could anyone try to help me?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found the solution, which can be read as an answer that I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948103/how-adjust-my-app-in-android-11-in-cell-phone-screen/72817062#72817062) to my original question .