# Fullscreen Mode in Samsung Devices

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm developing an application for Android and I'm having a problem with Samsung devices, because on all devices it is in fullscreen, but not on Samsung devices, so I saw that inside the Samsung menu there is an option similar to the one in the print below. And I realized that my application does not appear in this option, has anyone had a similar problem and how did you get the application to appear in this option? Below is the code of my Activity, demonstrating the flags I'm using, the software is being made in C# with Maui, but if you have examples in Java or Kotlin it will also help since I can adapt them.

[image: Existing function in Samsung cell phones]

```html
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{   
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {           
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        CheckDeepLink();
    }
    public override global::Android.Views.View OnCreateView(global::Android.Views.View parent, string name, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        if (parent is null)
            return parent;
        var resources = context.Resources.GetIdentifier("config_navBarInteractionMode", "integer", "android");
        var fabricante = DeviceInfo.Manufacturer;
        Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        Window.InsetsController.Show(WindowInsets.Type.StatusBars());
        Window.InsetsController.Show(WindowInsets.Type.NavigationBars());
        WindowCompat.SetDecorFitsSystemWindows(Window, false);
        return base.OnCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }

    private void CheckDeepLink()
    {
        Intent intent = Intent;
        var action = intent.Action;
        var stringLink = intent.DataString;
        if (Intent.ActionView == action && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringLink))
        {
            try
            {                   
                var linkUri = new Uri(stringLink);                    
                App.Current.SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived(linkUri);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could this be what you want? [How adjust my app in Android 11 in cell phone screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72817062/10528003)

Comment: So I'll explain it better, I have a Samsung Galaxy S22 and apps like Huawei and Netflix for example they are full screen, but the app I'm developing in the camera area it doesn't cover the whole screen, it has a black bar at the top, which it shouldn't, and then I saw this function inside my phone, the question is that my app doesn't appear in this list and about what you commented I already tried this and it didn't change anything :(